# How to turn off auto generate columns in table grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Hi I would like to add new column to table but its inpossible cause by auto generation. Could someone tell me how to turn off this function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Grafana v4.2.0 table options are different. Try to update your Grafana to see new features.

[image]